# 12V lead-acid battery charger with LM317 current limiter

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

I've got a Vsrc of 14.97 crossing a LM317 current limiter ( 1.25V / 1.25R = 1A), and at the output of the LM317 I have 14.4V/1A. So far so good.

Next I use a BC239 NPN transistor to switch a P-channel IRF9630 MOSFET with a 4K7 pull-up. Source is wired to 14.4V positive terminal, and I plan to put a charging load on Drain.

My battery is a 12V/9Ah, so charging would be done at ~C/10, and elsewhere I use a zener diode to read the battery's voltage, and cut-off charging at 13.6V, also cut-off loads at
10.8V (that's done with a relay, it's not relevant to this question).

My question is probably simple to answer: What gotchas should I be aware of when charging a >100Wh battery?

Comment: What should the purpose of the  _1-2A diode_ be? What is the type of your battery? Lead Acid, LiIon, ...?

Comment: Lead-acid. To prevent flowback into the charger circuit.

Comment: E.g. if my Vsrc (currently a laptop charger, later it will be a solar panel with blocking diode) goes low. I don't want gremlins in my circuitry.

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: If you haven't browsed Battery University web site already, it's a mother lode of information on battery issues: [Charging Lead Acid](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery).

Comment: No schematic and you keep dribbling out details of the circuit. I suspect there are a number of things wrong with your design, but since you can't be bothered describing it properly ...

Comment: @BruceAbbott A 317 current limiter with its vout connected to a P MOSFET (IRF9630 driven with a BC239 NPN). MOSFET is pulled up with 4K7 resistor, source to vin, drain to battery. 14.4V reaches battery. Would have used relay, but didn't have any. Doesn't matter, P = I^2 x R = 1 x 0.8 = 0.8W. I sense voltage with a 10V (9.49V) zener diode to an Arduino analog input. Draw the schematic in your head.

Comment: @auoa I thought initially I might  be using clamps (which cause a spike when attached), but I use screw terminals instead. I am not too experienced in protecting microcontrollers snd transistors from such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charging a **Lead Acid battery** is quite easy. You should first apply a constant current (CC) of max. 1C (in your case 9A) until the voltage reaches 14.4V. Hold this voltage for at least one hour, at most 10 house to balance the cells inside the battery. At the end of the constant (CV) period the current should be below 1/20 of C (in your case 450mA).
Do not apply voltage above 14.4V, this will reduce the capacity of the battery over time because of water loss.

Comment: That's a good answer. And what if I maintain charge at 14.4V/1A for the duration?

Comment: So your gonna charge with 1A in the constant current case? Just charge as long as the battery needs to reach the 14.4V.

Comment: Okay. And no need for diode blocking from the positive terminal of battery to MOSFET drain? I plan on making permanent connections to the battery, so there will never be sparks flying when I attach clamps.

Comment: I'll sense voltage at intervals of 600 seconds, having cut off charge 30 seconds before sensing. Am I alright here?

Comment: No, you don't have to stop charging while sensing the battery voltage. The mentioned voltage limits work while charging.

Comment: But I'd just read the charge voltage, not the battery voltage.

Comment: For posterity, I've decided to poll battery voltage (charge off) at intervals of 10 minutes. I cut off charge for 30s, sense voltage (10 samples 0.2s apart), wait 5s, charge again if necessary. Once target voltage of 13.6 is reached, no more charging occurs for 'a while'. Battery is sensed every 10 minutes, and charging begins again if necessary.

Comment: Now I got it ;-) Yes 13.6 or 13.5 is the fully charged settled voltage. Your battery will reach this approximately one hour after the last charging. Keep in mind that this voltages changes over temperature.

Comment: Yes, I noticed a Black&Decker charger stopped at 13.5(it may have continued trickling), but after I disconnected it, a few hours later I had only 13.3V

Comment: Thanks for your info, it's been greatly appreciated and assimilated. Unfortunately my LM317T current limiter is misbehaving, despite VREF / OHMS = 1.25V / 1.25R = 1A; after the MOSFET I see only an output of .25-.3A. I have 8 parralel 10Rs and a 0.1uF cap on this, should be solid :/

Comment: Your cap is far to small for this old linear regular, try at least 4.7uF at input and output of the LM317

Comment: Alright, thanks. Ordered a DMM that can sense capacity, but for now I'll go digging in my drawers. Do you know how it should be labelled? (the link that led me to use 0.1uF is http://diyaudioprojects.com/Technical/Current-Regulator/ )

Comment: On both input and output? You mean two 4.7uF caps?

Comment: " Unfortunately my LM317T current limiter is misbehaving" - Maybe not. If you are using any sort of voltage and trying to pull 1.25 amps, you will dissipate 1.25 watts per volt of differential voltage. Assuming you have a TO220 with no heatsink, your 317 is getting hot and going into thermal limit. Put a decent heatsink on it.

Comment: I tested it with a thermometer. I have a heatsink on it. It goes up 4-5 degrees celsius. The current pulled drops more and more as the battery approaches 13.6V.

Comment: @auoa Seems the answer to the capacitor question was that the battery was approaching full charge. Replaced the 0.1uF cap with a 0.33uF cap, no difference, dropped to 250mA current after a while. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Of course, the LM317 acts as limiter, so only the upper limit is restricted. This kind of regular can't _force_ a current, because it's unable to higher the voltage.